# aws cli shorthand json syntax

Tags: aws-cli

I'm trying to update the domain contacts for a couple of 100 domains using AWS cli with the shorthand syntax.

This works fine for .com domains:

```
    aws route53domains update-domain-contact --domain-name my domain.co.uk --admin-contact FirstName=Joe,LastName=Bloggs,ContactType=COMPANY,OrganizationName='MyOrg',AddressLine1='MyAddress1',AddressLine2='MyAddress2',City='MyCity',CountryCode=GB,ZipCode='MyPostCode'
```

However for .co.uk domains you need to specify the UK_CONTACT_TYPE in the ExtraParams and I can't figure out what the correct syntax should be

Something like this:

```
  aws route53domains update-domain-contact --domain-name my domain.co.uk --admin-contact FirstName=Joe,LastName=Bloggs,ContactType=COMPANY,OrganizationName='MyOrg',AddressLine1='MyAddress1',AddressLine2='MyAddress2',City='MyCity',CountryCode=GB,ZipCode='MyPostCode', ExtraParams=[{Name=UK_CONTACT_TYPE,Value=LTD}]
```

More info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53domains/update-domain-contact.html

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution? The 'invalid json' error is not very helpful...

Comment: I got it working by using the `--debug` option. There I was getting a hint on where the syntax error in the json was (missing quote).  


`aws route53domains update-domain-contact --debug --region us-east-1 --cli-input-json "$json"`

Also, I added the following `ExtraParams` to the registrant, admin and tech contact:

        "ExtraParams": [
          {
            "Name": "UK_CONTACT_TYPE",
            "Value": "value"
          },
          {
            "Name": "UK_COMPANY_NUMBER",
            "Value": "value"
          }
        ]